# Error running a Python job on DSE 4.8 Spark cluster.

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, datastax-enterprise

I've just came up with a weird problem running Spark (pyspark) on DSE cluster 4.8. For some reason when the job is running I got tens of errors as described below. Does anybody know any way to shut this error in anyhow?

I am using the `dse spark-submit` command.

```
ERROR 2016-04-04 12:49:21,305 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 747
ERROR 2016-04-04 12:49:21,305 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 748
ERROR 2016-04-04 12:49:21,347 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 749
ERROR 2016-04-04 12:49:21,388 org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 750
```

Comment: Ok it seems a memory issue. Basically when the executor runs out memory, the errors start to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

When I see this message "Asked to remove non-existent executor" that means the executor crashed for a different reason and so obviously spark can't kill it. Look at the executor logs to find out why it has crashed.

It's also possible you have a networking problem and your driver and executor can't communicate. Have also seen this message in that case.

Comment: I see a lot of these errors:
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 3579314176 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /cassandra/data/spark/worker/worker-0/app-20160404163740-0012/725/hs_err_pid3930.log. I'd appreciate a setup clue, ps. Thank you

Comment: This is also the output of the stderr: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000680000000, 3579314176, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)